# How to work on histograms in ERDAS Imagine?

Tags: erdas-imagine, histogram

Is there a possibility to work on histograms in ERDAS Imagine?

For example:

- Compare histograms of different images or different extents
- Shift them or find patterns

I thought there must be good options as ERDAS is specialized to work on images, isn't it?

I could hardly find any histogram options in ERDAS until now, though. The only things I found was 'histogram matching' which does not leave a lot of freedom...

Are there other options to work on a histogram in ERDAS, or to observe histograms and where can I find them?

Comment: i want to compare histograms of different images or different extents. comparing is the most important step. if i can shift them or find patterns that would be the best.

Comment: There are pretty good manuals for ERDAS Imagine available. I would start the search from the Field guide https://hexagongeospatial.fluidtopics.net/reader/uOKHREQkd_XR9iPo9Y_Ijw/khBQoaH4ne8R6PVMWZ7Ubw.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Be sure to have the **Home** tab selected in the ribbon and click on the **i** icon on the **Metadata** button.The Image Metadata dialog box will be displayed.Information is displayed for a default data layer (layer#1,i.e.,band #1). You can change the layer number to get the information for a different data layer if your data is multiband data, despite what the image is being displayed as in the viewer.It shows the spread and shape of the how the pixel values are distributed over all of the possible values for that particular band. The x-axis represents the digital number and the y-axis shows how many pixels in the image have that particular digital number. Explore the layers of the image and use the histogram to see how the digital number values of one band might or might not overlap with another band.Regarding comparison you may open two views at the same time and do the same above mentioned and see the differences.

Comment: thanks for the hint! I knew it must be somewhere close, but could just not see the button!
do you know by any chance how i can make the histograms appear even when I have a lot of NAs? i am now in the image metadata and can see all the buttons and also use almost all of them. only the histogram stays blanc... and i have a lot of NA values...

Comment: you mean histogram percentage? maybe rescaling the data help.